# Building an "odometer" for time spent on a server

Tags: c, bash, unix, timer

**I want to build an *odometer* to keep track of how long I've been on a server since I last reset the counter.**

Recently I've been logging quite a bit of time working on one of my school's unix servers and began wondering just how much time I had racked up in the last couple days. I started trying to think of how I could go about writing either a Bash script or C program to run when my .bash_profile was loaded (ie. when I ssh into the server), background itself, and save the time to a file when I closed the session.

I know how to make a program run when I login (through the .bash_profile) and how to background a C program (by way of forking?), but am unsure how to detect that the ssh session has been terminated (perhaps by watching the sshd process?)
I hope this is the right stack exchange to ask how you would go about something like this and appreciate any input.

Comment: see `last` command [http://linux.die.net/man/1/last]

Comment: You might consider using the modifiction time of your .bash_history to determine when you last ended your bash session. This will get more complicated if you ever launch multiple shells at once.

Comment: Running multiple shells at once is a problem I would run into.

Comment: Thank you @F.C. for the `last` command, I wasn't aware of that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your shell, you may be able to just spawn a process in the background when you log in, and then handle the kill signal when the parent process (the shell) exits.  It wouldn't consume resources, you wouldn't need root privileges, and it should give a fairly accurate report of your logged in time.

You may need to use POSIX semaphores to handle the case of multiple shells logged in simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what kind of signal is sent upon closing a sshd process? Does it just send SIGHUP to all its children?

Hadn't thought to use semaphores, but I like that approach.

Comment: I believe that is correct.  You may want to experiment with catching different signals to see which ones get sent.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered writing a script that can be run by cron every minute, running "who",  looking at its output for lines with your uid in them, and bumping a counter if it finds any?  (Use "crontab -e" to edit your crontab.)

Even just a line in crontab like this:

```
* * * * * (date; who | grep $LOGNAME)>>$HOME/.whodata
```

...would create a log you could process later at your leisure.

Comment: I'm not all to familiar with cron, but I will look into this. I'd ideally to create something that only runs when I'm logged in (ie. it isn't checking if I'm logged in when I'm not).